# 'Not connected to the database' on Django admin site with MongoDB through django-nonrel

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-nonrel

I am trying to configure the Django admin site for my django application by following the instructions here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/ .
I run the development server but when I try to access `/admin` url I get an error with a stack trace saying that there is no connection to the database. I'm new to django by I was assuming that I didn't need to explicitly create a connection to the database by using the django model layer. What am I missing?

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  178.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py" in process_response
  36.                 request.session.save()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mongoengine/django/sessions.py" in save
  48.         s = MongoSession(session_key=self.session_key)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py" in _get_session_key
  175.             self._session_key = self._get_new_session_key()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py" in _get_new_session_key
  167.             if not self.exists(session_key):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mongoengine/django/sessions.py" in exists
  34.         return bool(MongoSession.objects(session_key=session_key).first())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset.py" in __get__
  1151.         db = _get_db()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mongoengine/connection.py" in _get_db
  45.             raise ConnectionError('Not connected to the database')

Exception Type: ConnectionError at /admin/
Exception Value: Not connected to the database
```

I ran `manage.py syncdb` and I can see that the connection to the mongodb database works (it created several collections in my mongodb database). So in this case it just worked. What's different from the case above?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: I don't have it with me right now but I'll add it later to the question. Sorry about that.

Comment: @drcosta just edited the question and added the stacktrace.

Comment: Sorry, another question: where do you have the `connect()` call for mongoengine? In `settings.py`? Or in your `models.py`? I believe the recommendation is to put it in `settings.py`

Comment: I don't! I guess that's what is missing in my code. I didn't see a reference to that anywhere. So do I just put the mongoengine.connect() somewhere in the settings.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Posting as an answer so you can close the question)

Per [the docs](http://mongoengine.org/docs/v0.4/guide/connecting.html), you do need to explicitly connect to MongoDB using the `connect()` method. This can be a simple

```
connect('dbname')
```

If you're running MongoDB on your local machine, and also accepts keyword arguments for `host`, `port` (should be an `int`), `username`, and `password`, and additionally accepts the other keyword arguments that are valid for [pymongo.connection.Connection](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/connection.html#pymongo.connection.Connection)

Also per [the docs](http://mongoengine.org/docs/v0.4/django.html#connecting), the right place to put your call to `connect()` is in `settings.py`.

Comment: I'm still a little unsure of why `syncdb` appeared to work -- is it possible the collections were created by something else? Please let me know if you can figure that out.

Comment: that's right. After adding that to the settings.py it worked (well, not exactly, now I'm getting a different error but that's another story). However, I thought I didn't need to explicitly call the connect method, as I assumed that django-nonrel would somehow do it. Also, I can guarantee you that syncdb worked before and it was the one creating those colletions in the db.